# Как вычислить значение функции в строке подставляя значения в JS

Tags: javascript, математика

Как можно вычислять значение математической функции представленную в виде строки?

Например: `f(x,y) = 2*x + 5/y`

Как можно подставить x и y, затем вычислить значение функции,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел отличную библиотеку для решения задачи "math.js":

```
var f = "2*x^2 + sqrt(5/y)";
var fx = 2;
var fy = 5

var node = math.parse(f);
console.log(node.eval({x: fx, y: fy}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var f = "f(x,y) = 2*x + 5/y";
var x = 100;
var y = 2.5;

f = f.replace(/f\(x,y\)\s=\s/g, ""); //удаляем лишнее
f = f.replace(/x/g, x); // заменяем подстроку x на значение переменной x
f = f.replace(/y/g, y); // тоже самое с y
f = eval(f); // вычисляем значение строкового выражения

console.log(f);
```

Comment: А если в функции есть степень, корень, косинус, синус и т.д.? Знаю, что можно подставлять Math.pow(), Math.sqrt() и т.д. Есть ли какой-нибудь готовый код для этого? не хочется свой велосипед делать

Comment: Готовый код есть, но надо найти. Это уже в гугл.